# What is the origin of your SO username?

Tags: discussion, fun

What is the origin of the name you use on Stack Overflow or if you use your Real Name on Stack Overflow, what's the origin of any online handle you use?

**Most Popular Reasons**

- Uncontrollable Circumstances (birth)

(Adding reasons as they come in...)

Comment: Etymology == wrong word?

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed. It was a wiki to begin with, it's a part of Stack Overflow, and I can write pages on why it's at least as relevant as 'Facts about Jon Skeet'.

Comment: Etymology is the wrong word. I had to change it, or else the investment in my linguistics education would be all for naught.

Comment: Thank you. I sometimes use big words without knowing what they mean.

Comment: Also, reopening. It's not downvoted and it's Wiki'd and tagged.

Comment: @Gortok, I'm flabbergasted at the audacity of your shenanigans apropos this gregarious epistolary notice about cognomens.

Comment: What's funny is that I know all except one word (cognomens).

Comment: Cognomen == name. BTW, Etymology is the study of the history of words and how they enter language. So your usage wasn't completely incorrect, just not completely correct either. And origin is a better word anyway.

Comment: It *is* a better word, you're right. It's as Mark Twain said, The difference between the right word and the almost right word is like the difference between "Lightning" and "Lightning Bug"

Comment: I'm amazed that this question has been downvoted a net amount of three times.  It started as a wiki, has stayed a wiki, and is in the same vein as many other questions.  I don't think I'll ever understand some people's motivations.

Comment: My motivation is pure profit. Or boredom. Whichever comes first.

Comment: Usually, boredom comes first. Even on dictionary. =)

Comment: We are Digg. Resistance is futile. You will be assimilated.

Comment: Can't tell whether I'm on this topics comments or on an IRC channel

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: @Seventh Element: That's why it has the 'not-programming-related' tag on it. :-)

Comment: It was the result of my mother standing on her head to get pregnant.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Many years ago, in the dark days before mobile phones, I was involved in a BBS meet where everyone swapped home phone numbers online before University broke up for the holidays. We were mostly new to this kind of thing, and didn't think to swap real names as well.

Cue following awkward phone conversation with someone's mother:

```
Me:   "Hello... can I speak to... *[suddenly realises the problem]* 
       er...  CaptainNemo, please?"

Her:  "What? Who is this?"

Me:   "Um... sorry. Ok, this is weird.... but do you by any chance
       have a son or daughter who's studying computers at university 
       and is home for the holiday?"

Her:   "Oh... you mean Paul. Hang on. Who shall I say is calling?"

Me:    "Great, thanks. Tell him it's... ah... JabbaTheHutt."
```

I started making a point of using my real name for stuff shortly after that.

Comment: I changed mine when I suddenly realized that co-workers were calling me by my screen name.

Comment: @Tom - was that by any chance, Neo?

Comment: Ah yes, as well as the joys of 'voice validating' accounts.

Answer (score 52):

Stack Overflow doesn't have a handle on Jon Skeet. Jon Skeet has a handle on Stack Overflow.

Oh wait, wrong post.

Comment: ROFLMAO.. (It was supposed to be 'LOL', but the 10 character limit hit.

Comment: lol                       .

Comment: The 10 char limit is mostly a suggestion.

Comment: lol to 10 characters limit.

Comment: wow how did you lol? oh wait, that was before enforcing the 15 char limit?

Comment: yeah, it seems like they enforce the 15 chars much tighter now.  You used to be able to use a ​0x200B character (zero width space) which shows up as nothing, but still counted towards the character limit, but it seems they have disabled that now :(

Comment: Showoffs.

Z:-(

(Ok, it said "585 characters left", but then told me I need 15 characters. It looks like the code for this script got missed in the update.)

Answer (score 26):

[My Mom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother)

Comment: Almost         .

Answer (score 22):

I'm a Kiwi and I'm a Bastard

Comment: Well, at least you're honest about it. :-)

Comment: Kiwi's are small birds too.

Comment: Kiwi = New Zealanders

Comment: Yeah A Kiwi is our National Bird and how New Zealanders refer to ourselves. Bit like USA = Yank, Australian = Aussie, British = Whinging Pom ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't like being called Yank.  I'm from the US btw.

Comment: Maybe British = Wank?

Comment: +er, I guess.  ;}

Comment: NZ++ here as well (Although I live in Australia, so that makes me a Kwaussie)

Comment: Kwaussie is a quasi-name ;-)

Comment: ROFG (that's Rolling On the Floor Groaning :·)

Comment: Half Kiwi here.  But that wouldn't make a very good user name.

Answer (score 14):

**P**, because it's my first initial (my given name is "Pimp").

**Daddy**, because that's what my wife and kids (<sup><sub>*and your mom*</sub></sup>) call me.

*Edit*:

Seriously?  Down-votes?  WTF?

Comment: Not sure.  Wasn't me. I upvoted everyone who responded.

Comment: Some people just take themselves *way* too seriously, I think.

Comment: I'd encourage you to grow up.

Comment: @Jim: Can I interest you in a sense of humor?

Answer (score 10):

Ken Ray - I guess since that is what my parents thought would be a good name for their first-born, who am I to argue?

Comment: When you were growing up, did you go by "Little" and call your father "Sun"?

Answer (score 10):

My name comes from Magic: The Gathering where 'bolt bait' refers to a really annoying creature that desperately needs to be hit by a Lightning Bolt.  That's me.

Comment: If you're into stackoverflow & Magic, please check out this combination of the two: http://draw3cards.com/

Answer (score 9):

I'm nobody special

**edit:** to give context, before I became a moderator, I went by the username "nobody_" (before that "nobody", but I switched to "nobody_" when "nobody" was taken on Twitter)

Comment: I disagree.  For a 'nobody' you sure are somebody!

Comment: I think that when you name nothing it becomes something.

Comment: Heidegger? (http://www.science.uva.nl/~seop/entries/nothingness/)

Comment: "Nobody" brings to mind a Manson interview question... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2oZWpqtNi4

Comment: My secret's out!

Answer (score 8):

litb meant *"Linux Is The Best"* back then. Nowadays, it means *"Let It Be"*.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ whoami
ether
$ perl -wle'print substr((getpwent)[6], 0, 5)'
Ether
```

I've always used this userid, but I started going by this name in real life at a former company where I discovered on my first day that not only was there another developer who shared my first name, her desk was right next to mine. Everyone insisted that I needed to resolve the namespace collision; thankfully I was able to self-select my new identifier.

Answer (score 7):

*Seiti* comes from a romanized corrupted version to portuguese (I´m brazilian) of my japanese name:

```
清一
```

In fact, my 'real' name is **Sei-iti**.

It is a two parts name. The first half, '[sei](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MKJ%EF%BF%BD)', comes from the fact that every male member of my family (father, uncle, grandfather) has that initial on  their own names. The other half, Iti/ichi, it´s because I´m the first born son.

Answer (score 6):

I go with first name [dot] last name, in lowercase.  Of course there are places that don't allow me to do that, so if I can't use the dot, I will normally skip it.

I figure my parents went to all the trouble of making me, so I might as well use what I was given.

Comment: What happened to lowercase?

Comment: Good question.  I have no clue why I didn't do it in lowercase here.  All my email addresses and logins everywhere else are lowercase.  Strange - I honestly don't remember.

Comment: "All the trouble of making me"

Wow!

Answer (score 6):

Mine's got a history. :)

It all started back in 1997 when I changed schools (I was in 7th grade) and the new school had Internet (which was pretty rare at that time). The schools computer labs however were not really the latest-greatest things. Out of three rooms only one had Pentium-166 computers with Windows 95. The second best room had 486 CPUs with DOS running on them; and the last one had antique 286 CPUs that booted from the network (no hard drives in those computers!) and, naturally, also ran DOS.

Now, since most of the stuff was on DOS, there was also support for internet on DOS. "odipkt" it was called, I think. Using that, there was one great thing - IRC client. Now, since some computers didn't have hard drives, the program was stored on a network folder. To run it, you would have to copy it to your home folder and edit the configuration file. In the config file you had to change two things - the IP address (I usually picked a random one, not knowing how things work) and nickname.

The default nickname was "laacz" - which is a deliberately misspelled "bear" in my language. Since I didn't know what to choose, I took "Vilx" - which is similarly misspelled "Wolf" in my language. It also has the bonus of having the same first letter as my real name.

After that I stuck to this for a long time, since I was too lazy to figure out another one. I used it wherever nicknames were needed - games, internet forums, etc.

Eventually I met a colleague of my father's in the IRC. From him I learned the trick of adding "-" to the end of your nickname when it was already taken somewhere. And for me this was often the case, because it turned out that the idea of "Vilx" was not very original after all. ;)

A turning point came when my favorite internet forum grew large enough and migrated form a homebrew system to phpBB thus requiring everyone to re-register. I didn't do it immediately, and after a few days "Vilx" was already taken. Since then I've always used "Vilx-" everywhere, and so far it seems that this now IS original. Haven't met anyone else with the same nick. :)

Answer (score 6):

I have my username because I'm a big pussy... which is why I work at Initech to begin with.

But at least my name isn't Michael Bolton.

Answer (score 5):

"Gortok" is an amalgamation of my name, "GeORge sTOcKer" (emphasis added).

Comment: You don't write out your name like this "GeORge sTOcKer" regularly? :)

Comment: LOL.  Although I think it's rather neat that I share a namesake with a Star Trek character, even if he was a coward.

Answer (score 5):

I blame my <strike>serious lack</strike> *conservation* of originality.

*Thanks Sean!*

Comment: Why waste originality?

Answer (score 4):

My name's origin is obscure.

Back in the early 1990s, there was a television show called The Critic. The main character's mother was a blueblood socialite who suggested that all the poor people in New York City be blasted out into space.

After that, I started using "out into space" as a sort of meme among my friends. Various things should be blasted out into space. Like the service at Bennigan's. Or leaf blowers on Saturday mornings.

Several years later Out.Into.Space became my performance identity when I was in the slam scene in Dallas, Texas.

Now I'm old and fat and impatient and the only performance I care about is my code's, but Out Into Space has always stuck with me. Fourteen years and counting, old friend. QQ

Comment: Ah the Critic, good old Jay Sherman - pity it was cancelled, though there was at least a crossover with The Simpsons!

Comment: It got retooled so many times. Some really famous and popular writers worked on that show. Judd Apatow for example.

Comment: +1 for reminding me about _The Critic_

Answer (score 4):

Random typing, actually I was trying to type Sloughk (still doesn't make sense).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slough

Comment: lol yeah, actually I've been in Slough, may be it's some subconscious stuff :)

Comment: Come friendly bombs ...

Answer (score 4):

My name is Tony - nickname sometimes is "T" - Cousin randomly shouted to me (while slightly drunk) "Tea with two sugars?" - Sounded good and is now my new user name of most things.

Answer (score 3):

On Stack Overflow I use my name Jim C. On other sites I use Gray Raven which is the name of a DD character I played back in college which was more years ago then I care to think about.

Answer (score 3):

"AgentConundrum" comes from the main character on the TV show "[Seven Days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Days_(TV_series))," Frank Parker.

Parker is an NSA **Agent** whose code name is "**Conundrum**."

It was one of my favorite shows back when it was still on the air, mainly because I love time travel.

Comment: That show was riddled with holes. But I miss it.

Answer (score 3):

The history of my choice is no where near as interesting as some posted here, just a bit goofy..

Way back when I use to like a show called [Otherworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherworld_(TV_series)) which is just plain terrible, but it played in the 80s when I was way less selective about the quality of stuff I watch 
( maybe ). It only lasted 8 episodes, and rightly so. One of the episodes entitled ["Village of the Motorpigs"](http://www.guba.com/watch/3000127089), just sort of stuck in my mind for some reason, the way freaky stuff stays with you from your childhood like that Space 1999 episode called [Dragon's Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Domain) that still seems to freak me out 30 years later, [see for yourself](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tbXhu09m5s). Anyway the episode goes like this:

"The episode opens with the Sterling's traveling through the Forbidden Zone on board a rackety old bus owned by Velcrows Widley - a retired Zone Trooper. After being stopped by Zone Troopers, the bus is searched and the Sterling's are discovered, but before they can be taken away the bus is attacked by Motorpigs - a motorcycle gang. After being taken to their camp, the Motorpig's leader, Chalktrauma, decides to split up the family. Hal is sent to work in a chalk mine - chalk being a mineral that has a narcotic effect. The only one of the Motorpigs who doesn't take chalk is Chalktrauma who has decided he likes the look of Gina and starts making his plans. After talking with Pango - one of the other miners, Hal challenges Chalktrauma and, after killing him, the family make their escape through the mine when the Zone Troopers attack the camp." - taken from [www.paulmichaelglaser.org](http://www.paulmichaelglaser.org/1980s_dir.html)

I guess the name is just a touchstone to a fun childhood memory that makes me smile every time I see it, and I can use that every now and then... :)

Answer (score 3):

A few years ago some friends of mine introduced me to NetHack, which I somehow never managed to come across by myself even though a) I'm a bit of a gaming nut and b) the game has been around in some form or another for nearly 20 years. Since I was a NetHack noobie, and the first character class I gravitated to was a gnome, I named my character "Gnovice" (with a silent g). I kinda liked it, so I started using it for my various login IDs.

Comment: I like your avatar - from the cover of Era Vulgaris by Queens of the Stone Age.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: You're the first person to recognize Bulby!

Answer (score 2):

It's Track #2 from The Cult's Electric, and partly my last name.  It was given to me at the tender age of 13 or so (7th grade), when me and a friend (who introduced me to the band, among others) and I were beating Legend of Zelda.  A second friend heard it, and was born with the amazing talent to dictate people's nicknames, usually for life.  He liked it when he heard it and started calling me that, and pretty soon everybody was doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same handle as I've used ever since I hung out as sysop on the #Delphi group on EFNET IRC in the early-to-mid 90's, and originally it's the name of a Scottish Munro (mountain over 3000' ft) that I'd climbed around at that time.  Makes it about 15 or 16 years old.

I wonder if anyone can better that by a substantial margin?

Answer (score 2):

It is a shortening of the registered name of a horse I used to own, Holly's Little Gem.

Answer (score 2):

First initial followed by last name. I use this everywhere on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I use `b2gills`, some people in high school used to call me bgills. I would have used that everywhere, but it seems someone else used that on some sites. The number 2 comes from the fact that both my, and my mothers, initials are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Mine started as a misspelling (Simgnud instead of Sigmund) and then "Gnud" became sort of a joke with some non-virtual friends of mine. So now I use it online =)

Answer (score 2):

I'm terrible about thinking up names, handles, etc. So, at one point long ago when trying to think of a character handle for an old shooter my impatient friend said, "C'mon man, hurry up and think of something"

...and Sumptin was born.

Answer (score 2):

A deeply obscure physics joke.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_dimension#Orthogonality

Answer (score 2):

Years ago my sister introduced me to one of her co-workers, who thought my sister was creepy, because she had dressed at Halloween as Wednesday (of the Addams Family)

When she went to introduce me, I said I was Thursday, Wednesday's little sister.  He thought I was creepy too!  Plus, I'm a geek.  Oh, and I was born on a Thursday.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Isn't our name a purely subjective choice?  I can see upvotes for great names and circumstances, but downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

I am Bon Jovi. Yes, *that* Bon Jovi. I was going to use "Bon J" as a username, but that sounded weird. So I took a little creative license and changed it to "Jon B". Isn't that neat? It makes it look like I'm just some guy named "Jon B" and not a famous rock star.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember the exact reason, but I know I wanted a meta-ish name for my Meta SO account. And besides, changing your Meta name was the [fashionable thing to do at the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518). People have asked me if I picked my name just so I could make pages say "Closed by Popular Demand," but that's not it; I changed my name long before I was a 3k user.

Now that I think about it some more, I'm pretty sure it was so that any successful feature requests I made would be "by popular demand." You know, since ["We don't run [site name here]. The community does."](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

Justin John Nelson, and i'm a GUY

Comment: All I knew from the picture is that you're ugly.  :-P

Comment: Ha, thanks.  But, I think you are just jealous.

Comment: as opposed to jjngirl, she's out there somewhere!

Comment: Wait, you're a human too. Shouldn't it be jjnguyhuman?

Answer (score 1):

GameCat is just a name I use on message boards and some IRC channels. (There is at least one other person using that name.)

It just combines a hobby with a favorite animal.

Answer (score 1):

I would've used my full name, but got into a habit of abbreviating it years ago since the first thing I tried to use it in had a 7 character limit.

Answer (score 1):

I started to use this name several years ago. Although I don't remember how it was created, I can clearly remember the reason - I needed to call my Rougue for a modem multiplayer game of Diablo (1) with a friend of mine.

What great days we had then!!!

Answer (score 1):

Its a twist of my RL nick, which is always taken since its so short. Lately I haven't even bothered trying if its accepted anymore.

Answer (score 1):

My initials and an 'X' to give it a hackerish ring. See Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, I used to use "gustav" as my online name. It was the "German" name I was given in my high school German class, and when I made my first online email account (hotmail, ew!), I needed a name to go by, because back then it was a Bad Thing to put your real name on the internet.

Now that I'm all growed up, Gustav_25 isn't very professional, so I just go with my real name.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using 'madlep' about 15 years now for various things. Mainly gaming.

Started off as 'mad leprechaun' as I'm slightly... unusual in some thought patterns, and I'm of Irish descent (I was born and grew up in New Zealand though). Problem was in some older games, that was too long, and some wouldn't allow spaces. So it got abreviated.

It's a good handle, as I have *never* come across another madlep, and I always manage to get it as a login whenever I sign up for some new service or whatnot online.

Answer (score 1):

My dad wanted to name me Harpo, after the Marx brother.  The real Harpo would have kept his mouth shut instead of answering this question.

I was seen around here as [votenader.org](http://votenader.org) for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I used to deliver pizzas for Dominos back in the day when it was 30 minutes or $3 off - they called me the Nevster - I guess it has a flavour of fast cars or something...

Pizza delivery and hacking computer code - yes I'm a Neal Stephenson fan.

Answer (score 1):

There are English speakers who would be able to decode my ID readily, but I doubt there are many of them on SO.  Perhaps I am wrong - would be interesting to find out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an alien interpreter and I crash landed on this planet many years ago. I've been secretly pushing your technology towards faster than light travel so I can return home. One of the first people I met was a guy called Alan. Turns out he used my situation to [write a short story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skizz). I never saw a penny in royalties.

Skizz

Comment: If you actually know Alan Moore, respect+=1

Answer (score 1):

My favorite part in the Buffy musical was Anya's song about bunnies.. and so I have started to use this nick everywhere, itsbunnies. Creative, eh?

Answer (score 1):

My comes from my nickname of Ironsides because of my wheelchair

Answer (score 1):

Back in the college days I was (still am) the weird guy and had the habit of just kind of making up my own words as I went along (somewhat like Don King) or trying to add emphasize things with jibberish.

The normal thing I'd do when seeing some friends is say "Sup-a-Dillie-O!!!" or "Peace out homeskillets!!!" or "Hey, we going to hit Taco Bell for some grub-a-dillie-o or something?". One of my friends was an art major and was doing a comic series and using a bunch of us in the apartment complex for a project and I made it into the cartoon with the name of "Dillie-O".

It kind of stuck ever since. 8^D

Answer (score 1):

I stole it from a Ukranian Yak hearder.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is derived from Sourcecode. In dutch it is pronounced the same. It originated about 13 years ago when we had a small "demo crew" at school, nothing fancy. I was the main programmer and musician, so they called me sourcecode, thus Sorskoot was born.

Answer (score 1):

I used to be a lab manager at a synthetic DNA manufacturing facility. We made DNA primers - mostly for the Human Genome Project. One of the ends of a piece of the DNA we made was called the 3' (three prime) end and the other end was the 5' (five prime) end.

I had this job in the early/mid 90's and I worked 2nd shift. We had a lot of down time while the DNA was being made - so the company was nice enough to provide us with cable TV, a stereo, and full Internet access in the lab. Generally we would watch TV or goof around on the Internet while we waited on the DNA.

One night one of my co-workers and I signed up for some online text-based game. He chose the username 'threeprime' and I chose the username 'fiveprime'. I've used 'fiveprime' ever since.

Answer (score 1):

I was always called a "genius" growing up, even though I basically did nothing to prove that I was.  Everyone always saw "such potential" in me, but I never lived up to their standards of where they thought I should be.  I never bought into the "gifted and talented" label.

So, Worthless Genius it is.  In a way self deprecating, but it's realistic.

Answer (score 1):

My mother :)

Answer (score 1):

My mom and dad gave it to me. I try to stay away from the anon tags if I can.

Comment: I'm with you. I have grown more and more fond of my actual name, rather than nicknames, over the years.

Answer (score 1):

Malach means messenger or angel. I for sure do not think that I am an angel. But going to my profile you will find out that I'm something like a programming pastor. My calling into pastoral ministry is based on Malachi 2:5-7, where Malachi, the last prophet in the Old Testament, talks about Levi or the priest in general and calls him a messenger of God - see below. This makes for a nice little recursion, as Malachi (Hebrew for my messenger) calls the priest malach.

> My covenant with Levi was to give life
>   and peace. I kept my covenant with
>   him, and he honored me. He stood in
>   reverent awe before me. He taught the
>   truth and did not lie. He walked with
>   me in peace and uprightness. He kept
>   many out of the ditch, kept them on
>   the road. "It's the job of priests to
>   teach the truth. People are supposed
>   to look to them for guidance. The
>   priest is the **messenger of
>   GOD-of-the-Angel-Armies**. (Mal 2:5-7
>   MSG)

I decided to use my own name to make myself a little more visible on the net, though.

What I wanted to do using this nickname is to speak the word. I do believe that our words have power. God spoke a word, and spoke the world into existence doing this. Jesus spoke to the fig tree and it withered, spoke to sick people and they were healed. Peter spoke to the begar at the beautiful gate and he was healed. I can speak as well, speak healing, wellbeing, but also build my future through speaking truth over my life.

God called me to be a teacher in the body of Christ, a modern equivalent of the old testament priest, using the scripture above. So I speak it over me using the word *malach*, I am your messenger.

Comment: Awesome back-story. Good to see other involved in ministry on SO.

Comment: Aww, I thought you were actually named Malachi. I only know one person named Malachi.

Comment: I think I knew somebody named Malachi too. Sounds like they belong in a group of 300 Spartans. "I AM Malachi!"

Comment: This Malachi has a brother named after another minor prophet, actually.

Comment: Sorry I did not make this clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Short for 'Frederiek'.

'fretje' has always been my nickname, even before the days of the internets.
I am especially fond of the 't' in there. Most people spell it with a 'd' as in 'fredje', but I just don't like it that way (It doesn't look good IMHO), and also the pronunciation in dutch (I'm from Belgium) is better with a 't'.
I also like it to be all lowercase.

Comment: What is the correct pronunciation of it?

Answer (score 1):

whY SHoUlD I TELl yoU

I've been using it since I was like 12, and it's been available just about everywhere, so it works out nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Twin Peaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Peaks), so I record people saying "Nosredna," then play it backward to hear my last name.

Answer (score 1):

Initials of my Quake2 online name: "GutsButNuts"

Answer (score 1):

I introduce [Trogdor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trogdor#Trogdor_the_Burninator). And the Trogdor comes in the NIIIIIGGGHHTTTT!

You can also check out my profile description: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131932/troggy

My image was also was a partial community choice as seen here: [Troggy needs an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30462/troggy-needs-an-image)

[image: trogdor]

Answer (score 1):

My current display name is derived from the R-9DH Grace Note, a ship from the game R-Type Final. It's also the name of my personal laptop, because she has many features similar to the ship. She's sleek and slim, she's *gorgeous*, she's futuristic-looking, she's silvery-coloured, she has a light blue tinted HUD that matches the tint on the ship's canopy, her LEDs match the details on the ship, she has a beautiful sounding name, and she has an Extended Photon Belt Wave Cannon.

I actually kinda like the name, too, it sounds nice on the tongue and almost looks like a proper full name (even if my name isn't Grace). So this one is probably a keeper.

My original display name, ccomet, is just an abbreviation of the email address I used for my gravatar when I first posted an answer to Stack Overflow. It was always kind of a dull name, I only kept it because I generally avoid changing names online in order to avoid confusing people on who I am. Some mechanical kerfuffles superceded my comfort with the name, so I have basically ended that name. But I still like the gravatar for that email, anyway.

Comment: And a Grace Note is a type of note in music.

Comment: @Arlen The entire series of R-9DH models are musically inclined, actually. The R-9DH3 is Concertmaster, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using chegueverra, ever since I began my life revolution of working in IT.
I was going nowhere and almost living in a dump ... Everytime, I face a problem or get a bit down on myself, I remember what it was like before ...

Comment: I just hope you don't piss off the Bolivian government.

Comment: I'm not planning any trips there soon ... :P

Comment: And why CheGueVerra and not CheGuevara? :-/

Comment: I don't claim to be him, so it's more symbolic

Comment: @Out Into Space: If all those T-Shirts don't piss them, he wouldn't either! :)

Comment: you really might want to do some research on this man, not exactly a positive role model...

Comment: @utku karatas: I saw one of those once with the caption "I died for the cause and all I got was this lousy t-shirt"

Comment: +1 for picking a different visage and name.  That guy was about as evil as they come.  Amazing PR they do on him though.

Comment: @andrew: A friend had one that said: *Your hero is dead.* and in the back: *My army killed him.* To give a little more context, I *am* an argentinian (why do you think he got called *che*?) and my friend *is* on the army. (Currently being right or center arround here == murderer, "facho", and many many other **bad** things... at least in public. Will need to remember to delete this post if I put my real name... Just in case. I prefer to be apolitical http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2c7ZZNcWsA ).

Answer (score 0):

Firstname + first letter of lastname = small amount of anonymity on the internets...

Answer (score 0):

Mine is stolen directly from 'Drawn Together' where it was the name of one of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Too many Dilbert cartoons around my desk (according to my pointy haired boss that is!)

Answer (score 0):

'cuz **I am Mohit Nanda!**

Answer (score 0):

I've been "Galactic Cowboy" or some variant for as long as I've been online.  Back in the dark ages of the early 90's, the Galactic Cowboys were one of my favorite bands (still are, but that's beside the point...) and it was just a cool-sounding name.  If you look closely at my avatar, his t-shirt has a Galactic Cowboys logo.

On many sites you can't have a space or other symbols in the name, so I just gave up long ago and ran them together.

So, yeah, I've been "Galactic Cowboy" for more than 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

epaga ist agape backwards.

Answer (score 0):

initials T K and tkforeverer... it's longer than forever and the domain was taken.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago in High School, I decided I would make up my own language.

I was a huge Mac fan at the time (this is ~1997) and I wanted to be able to say "Death to IBM".  So the word I picked for "death" was "kogus".  Seemed cool at the time, but sometimes I wish I had just used my real name.

Answer (score 0):

It is an abbreviation of my name... the algorithm that is to select the letters of your first, middle, and last name up to and including the first vowel, then also include the consonant following the first vowel of your last name.  Twisting the rules is necessary if names start with vowels or end with vowels.

For example, John Harold Smith would be johasmit, Jane Lynn Doe would be jalydo (no trailing consonant, Lance Abert Campbell would be labecam, you get it.

Answer (score 0):

They call me so at work, my real name is Massimo and maghis is shorter and sound similar. They often call me Mago too (means "mage" in italian :D)

Answer (score 0):

My last name, spelled backwards. It's both easier to spell and easier to pronounce that way. I like it because it sounds menacing and silly at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

My day job currently involves maintaining a CRUD++ app, and my username comes from one of the test contacts we have on our development version of the app.

There's nothing stopping anyone senior in the company from logging into our dev system besides not knowing the URL and not knowing (insecure) login details, so anything offensive or insulting is out of the question.  So, in order to be humorous and have a little fun, some of our test data veers into silly territory.  Who in their right mind would found a company called 'Inflatable Dartboards 'R Us'?

One notable contact has the lyrics to the theme tune of *Fraggle Rock* as his address, but since that one's a bit of an in-joke to us, I've chosen another one whose name describes the data in our dev system.

Answer (score 0):

Long ago, in a time where Commodore 64s were common with puny 300 baud modems, there was a BBS where I used the handle, "Mr. PizzaMan," as I do enjoy the food now called a 'za to me and figured I'd take it as my name since I was named after my father.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booji_Boy

(Yes, I'm a big Devo fan).

Answer (score 0):

Back in college I got into Starcraft and playing online on battle.net. I don't remember the name I used at first but my roommate and I got good enough (it helped we played in the same room) and actually were ranked pretty highly. One game I was playing Protoss and our opponents were Zerg and when I sent in a bunch of zealots and ravaged one of the enemies he said "u made me, instantsoup!"

I don't believe he was intentionally calling me "instantsoup" but his poor grammar stuck and I became InstantSoup!

Answer (score 0):

Its my name and I am a nerd so:

Rick Schott + Nerd = _rick_schott

Answer (score 0):

An anagram of my name. It's simple to figure out for those who know or care about my real name, and distinctive for those who don't care.

Comment: Richard Highou?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Mr. Vile as my online name for about 3 years, it was originally based upon a video game character from the game "Banjo-Kazooie" on N64, Mr. Vile is a red crocodile.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed mine from a Phone Book after I had to get a new one following a little accident involving "negotiations". I swear, it was an accident!

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Sampson. I used to use other names online, but soon realized that it would benefit me to use my real name, and thus associate all of my activity online with my person. Since doing so, my Google-rankings have climbed, I get job-offers more frequently, and I am overall happier. Just need to be careful about what I do online.

Answer (score 0):

It's the name of my first Dungeons and Dragons character.  Yes, this is somewhat geeky.  "Beska Miltar" from the suggested character names in the back of the original B1 module.  Whee!

Answer (score 0):

I just use my name everywhere in the hopes to rule the first page on [Google results for my name](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=andreas+blixt)! Now that I've got 9 out of 10 for my name, I'm going for [just my last name](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=blixt) as well (only 1 out of 10)! Who says success can't be measured in Google rank?

Also, "Blixt" is what everyone calls me in real life, so it's a pretty natural choice. `=)`

Answer (score 0):

I do own the Google search for my name (Chacha102). So that is pretty much the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago when I first signed up for an MSN instant message account, I looked at my default profile and it had randomly selected a nickname for me. Lo and behold Soldier Moth was born

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a Simpsons reference. "Disgruntled Goat" was one of the supplementary Itchy & Scratchy characters mentioned in the episode "Itchy & Scratchy Land".

Answer (score 0):

Does SO enforce unique usernames?
My chose username was taken on one openid provider so I just used the next one provider in the list.
There is of course no reason why the other mgb on the first provider should use it here - but what if they did?

Answer (score 0):

Mine originates from my university way back in 2000. We automatically received an email box with autogenerated names from our initials and a seemingly random number: k for Karnok (last name), d for David (first name), 304 random integer.

Answer (score 0):

[Start Trek](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmemory-alpha.org%2Fen%2Fwiki%2FV%2527Ger&ei=Xwl6SsOVMoqutgfwxt2WCQ&usg=AFQjCNEJKBC5RnUyu5NTSOlk4pw3qmp2_A&sig2=OCxABL5tgxDoPUbqLrc7fQ). (I'm not a trekkie.)

Answer (score 0):

I chose mine while imagining strings that I couldn't find on Google. I particularly grew fond of some of them, and I keep using them, some as screen-names, others as passwords. I do like the name because I never get into any availability conflicts anywhere on the web that I'd like to register.

Comment: There's actually a small community of people interested in [Googlenopes](http://googlenope.com/about.php).

Answer (score 0):

A [town](http://maps.google.com/maps?&q=vossem+belgium) in Belgium, most likely + my parents.

Answer (score 0):

back in the day when I was younger, some members of the bike club I was in thought I looked like a I had a quiff like Bill Haley. From Bill Haley and the comets.

A little bit of clever jiggery pokery and you get cometbill.

Answer (score 0):

From the days when I was heavily addicted to Minesweeper (or was it Tetris?). A typo when bashing out my name for the latest high score.

It stuck, and has been with me ever since.

*(Browsing through these answers 18 months later, it's interesting to observe that a LOT of users have switched to their real names)*

Answer (score 0):

[From](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filburt) the cartoon [Rocko's Modern Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocko%27s_Modern_Life).

Answer (score 0):

I got mine from Wikipedia, and, though I don't use it on StackOverflow, I used it on anything that has a wiki, and am starting to use it elsewhere. When I signed up on WikiPedia, Arlen was taken, so I just added 22 to the end of it, and now I am known as Arlen22 on IRC, WordPress, and WikiMedia, along with most wikis.

Answer (score 0):

My nickname is a concatenation of the first two characters of each name part of my full name *Bauke Luitsen Scholtz*. It was invented at 1995 when I as being a kid created a small [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) DOS Batch program to select DOS games out of my collection and directly run it: "Gamemenu made by BALUSC". It had a blue [Norton Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Commander) like UI with keyboard navigation and the games were definied as `name=executionpath` pairs in an ini file. It was for personal purposes only.

Later when I for the first encountered Internet and joined the IRC chatrooms at 1996, this acronym was used as nickname to identify myself. After quickly becoming more familiar with the [netiquette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nettiquette) and having learnt that CAPS == SHOUTING, I decided to lowercase the middle characters so that the nickname "BalusC" was born. The last character is still uppercased, because "everyone did it also", referring to the so-called good old [l33t speak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L33t_speak).

Up to now this nickname is still pretty unique (only at Youtube there's someone who uses the same nickname and that's not me) and practically all [Google hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=balusc) refers to myself and/or my (former) website(s).

You're free how to pronounce it: *ba-lusj* or *ba-lusk*. I don't care, I'm deaf. Just wave to me :)

#### See also:

- [BalusC at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3ABalusc)

Answer (score 0):

My nick comes from an Esperanto sentence (*kiam la luno renkontas la sunon*: "when the moon meets the sun"). I sometimes use it shorted as kiam, which seems to be a name in some languages (I don't know exactly in which one).

Answer (score 0):

Timothy Richard Green = TRiG

I invented it for myself when I was still in primary school. Then, in college, I joined h2g2 and used it there. It's stuck ever since.

I usually sign my posts too, putting my TRiG (and a smiley, usually) at the bottom of each. The StackExchange sites are the only ones I don't do this.

I also sign posts on Facebook, because I find real names confusing. (Most of my Facebook friends are Internet friends first met on other communities where pseudonyms are the norm.)

Answer (score 0):

Mine originated as creed, but since 1996 (yes I've been on the internet that long), all websites on the face of the earth have had creed registered due to some band. Perhaps you've heard of them? So I just slapped on the country I live in to add some flair and originality to it.

Answer (score -1):

i am the man

Comment: How'd your interview go, btw?  Did you guess correctly on the whole man running vs. man walking bit?  I found the answer on Google, btw. :-)

Comment: lol, well besides the whole "deleting-question-before-theman-gets-an-answer" thing, i think it went alright.