# Troggy needs an image?

Tags: discussion, images, gravatar, daily-reputation-badges

I have decided to change the picture that represents all that is Troggy.  The default triangle square design has served its time.  It is time to put something up that defines Troggy across all the sites.  So, what should I change it to?  I have a few ideas, but haven't come down to a solid decision yet.  Maybe a picture of burning peasants or a Chuck Norris beard/fist?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131932/troggy

I might need to borrow some artistic talent from you guys. I can code, I just can't draw.

Decisions decisions...

RESULTS:

Trogdor on paper wins unless someone does make some awesome bear dragon beard fist man. Trogdor does have the beefy arm fist. So got the dragon and fist part taken care of.

FINAL:

There we go. Thanks goes to waffles for the fine photo.  Now you all can stare in awe at him. Flex it troggy!

Comment: how about a froggy with the head of a ... train??

Comment: a dragon....bear?

Comment: Wonder what a beard/fist looks like.

Comment: Who voted to close as spam?!

Comment: Don't look at me, I'd vote as too localized.

Comment: @Troggy, I cut you up an HD image of trogdor, in case your prefer it to the black and white one ... it will render better when its small

Comment: @waffles: That would be cool.  I do have a cool color version of trogdor somewhere.  You are right though, the ouline BW version would be more ideal for a small image.

Comment: @Troggy, I edited cigars answer and chucked it there, it may need to be cropped a tiny be tighter ... also the V shaped eyebrows may need a bit of bolding so they are not lost when small.

Comment: What's up, Troggy? We want to see the new gravatar!

Comment: There we go, thanks to waffles for the edit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need [Trogdor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trogdor#Trogdor_the_Burninator). Just sayin.'

[image: Burninating the countryside, burninating the peasants]
<sub>(source: [trilliumcg.com](http://trilliumcg.com/mattsworld/Images/trogdor.jpg))</sub>

And the Trogdor comes in the NIIIIIGGGHHHHTTTTTT!

Or in HD...

[trogdor http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/1050/trogdor.gif](http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/1050/trogdor.gif)

---

Comment: This would make a good tattoo.  Come to think of it, the dragon should have *this* tattooed on *his* arm.

Comment: @Bill: Like this? http://www.bme.com/tattoo/A80210/high/npu1-trogdor-the.jpg

Comment: @Cigars: almost... but to be truly self-referential *that* dragon needs the same thing tattooed on his arm...

Comment: @~quack: But then the dragon wouldn't be Trogdor ... Trogdor doesn't have tattoos!

Comment: Alrighty, you win. Unless someone does make some awesome bear dragon beard fist.

Comment: W00T! (plus 15)

Answer (score 4):

Don't tell him!

[alt text http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/5374/norrisbeardhair.jpg](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/5374/norrisbeardhair.jpg)

Comment: Looks like Al Borland!

Comment: Who's Al Borland?

Comment: So, you've never watched *Tool Time?*

Comment: What's *Tool Time*?

Comment: I really like this one too.

Comment: Who's going to be Tim "the tool-man" Taylor then?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some more ideas to choose from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troglodyte

Comment: Interesting idea, not sure if it would work great in a little icon though.

Answer (score 3):

... there is only another fist.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Does anyone have [a stack of delicious waffles](http://food-easy-recipes.webseomasters.com/food-images/waffles.jpg) as their gravatar yet?

Comment: ☰☰☰☰☰☰☰ ♡ ☰☰☰☰☰☰☰☰☰

Comment: Mmmmm... buttery, syrupy waffles.

Comment: waffles does have that taken care of, so I'll let him keep his waffle glory.