# Which user’s avatar/gravatar has impressed you most?

Tags: discussion, fun, subjective, gravatar, profile-picture

I really can't help but to put this question up after reading:
[Which user’s About Me section has impressed you most?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31781/)

I have one to start the ball rolling:
[Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey)'s
[image: mei]
The chinese character means "beautiful" (pronounced `mei`)

Comment: I haven't seen any interesting so far.

Comment: @Developer Art: Yours looks pretty cool too!

Comment: Need to split out your ball from the question. We're voting for what, the question or your suggestion?

Comment: Ah man, the hitler avatar question got deleted.

Comment: @random: There's no need to vote. Just sharing. If a similar question got deleted, oh well, let this be then. :)

Answer (score 2):

[image: TheTXI]

[TheTXI](http://www.ponyoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

I think mine was pretty cool because it had community involvement: Thanks to [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) for the hd version and edit and thanks to [John](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14048/) for the original suggestion.

[Troggy needs an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30462/troggy-needs-an-image/30468#30468)

[trogdor http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/1050/trogdor.gif](http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/1050/trogdor.gif)

Comment: And the Trogdor comes in the niiiiiiiiiiiiight!

Answer (score 1):

[Akdom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145/akdom) and his [kaleidoscope lasers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/swastikas-in-fractal-images/32009#32009)!