# How can we address compound badge tags on Meta? (i.e. let's group [epic] and [legendary])

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, badges, meta

After running into [this question on the Legendary badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50766/), I remembered quite clearly there was a discussion about the calculation and its delay, but I searched through the `[legendary]` tag to no avail. Thinking I was dreaming about it, I decided to leave it for official statement... until S.Mark posted [the question I had been thinking about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49727/). No wonder I never found it: it was tagged `[epic]`!

In general, there's no need to distinguish between these badges in the tags. In reviewing all of the questions tagged with [epic] or [legendary] (excepting [Troggy's "epic" gravatar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30462/), the actual content of the answers and the questions is the same, just with 50 days versus 150. In some cases they're referred to in pairs, and in general they exist as a pair for nearly any question that could be asked about them. So all keeping two separate tags does is divide the results, especially since some of those posts [already have 5 tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35350/).

Other examples of sets of badges which we *actually have questions for* include Good/Nice/Great Question, Good/Nice/Great Answer, and Popular/Notable/Famous Question.

So, given all this, **what are your thoughts towards phrasing for compound badge tags on Meta**? We can't have a slash in tags, so we can't do something like `[epic/legendary]`. Some possible options...

- `[epic-legendary]` - Standard hyphen-concatenation.
- `[epic-legendary-badges]` - Most badge tags are implied by virtue of the badges (like `[pundit]`), but if you pair two together it might help to include the word "badges".
- `[epic-and-legendary]` - Kinda unwieldy sounding but an option nonetheless.

**EDIT**

Well, Jeff went ahead and made the decision to pick simple hyphen-concatenation for compound tag badges. We've still got some days left for the bounty, so I'll wait until then before accepting an answer, in case anyone else wants to say a few words.

Comment: Also Enthusiast/Fanatic.

Comment: [I did this three days ago.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50351/does-deleted-activity-count-towards-enthusiast-fanatic)  Didn't occur to me to ask a separate question about it.

Comment: Actually, Mortarboard also, for 1 day rep-cap, but Mortarboard looks bug clean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an exceedingly minor issue, but I merged them into [epic-legendary]

Comment: What about, say, `[enthusiast-fanatic]`?  Or questions that applied to only Epic and not Legendary?  I thank you for taking action, but it seems you missed the larger issue while focusing on the specific example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for [epic-legendary] or the other "compound" tags you mention.  If you're discussing the [daily-reputation-limit] <sup>(I'd have named it [rep-cap], but *shrug*)</sup>, then that seems a better tag than either of the badge tags or some amalgamation.

I have run into the 5 tag limit more than once, however, and increasing that also solves this problem (given questions can be tagged/retagged with both as relevant).

Comment: I'm not speaking of the [reputation-cap] itself, I'm targetting the tag badges that are used to describe issues with badges themselves. Or are you suggesting that we be rid of all of the badge-specific tags? How would you tag a question about how one didn't receive the Legendary badge?