# Migrated questions retain old usernames on Community Wiki questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, questions, migration, community-wiki

This may be an edge case, but if you look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/what-is-the-origin-of-your-so-username/30933#30933) (admittedly ancient) Stack Overflow question that was migrated to Meta, you can see my old user name "Gortok" on the percentage of ownership under the question.

This appears to be a bug. But it could also be a feature. Even if it is a bug, I'm not sure it's one that needs to be fixed, since it only appears to affect migrated questions where the user has changed usernames — a rarity at best.

Comment: On meta it's not so rare. :)

Comment: I think I've also seen this on less-ancient posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not limited to migrated questions; it can happen to any CW post. [According to Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design/47522#47522), it's by design; names are stored in a denormalized field.

Comment: Logging old name by design only in CW seems weird, doesn't it?