# Looking for advertisement for switching away from VSS

Tags: discussion, advertising

While clicking through some pages, an ad for switching away from VSS came up briefly. Unfortunately, I navigated away as I recognized what it was for. Is there any way for me to find it again?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14716/sponsor-gallery-page-or-something-like-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sponsor Gallery is still on the to-do list... but, you're probably talking about the [VSS Is Dead](http://vssisdead.com/?so) campaign from Source Gear.

[http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/728x90VSS.png](http://vssisdead.com/?so)

http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/728x90ANN.png

And yes, VSS will mess you up like that.

Comment: Thanks. That second one is the one I was looking for. I did find another ad from the same campaign by refreshing over and over, but the ads from this campaign did not come up frequently.

Comment: Wow. I like that ad. Especially the bit about VSS being dead. Why do I never see any good ads on SO itself?

Comment: Shouldn't you have made that link an ad link? Also the images could be links too :)

Comment: Did they get that pic from runawaymethaddictstockphotos.com?

Answer (score 0):

Keep refreshing the page until it comes up again. :)

That is what I did once.

Comment: See that you ended up using the burninator

Comment: Yes, thanks to waffles for the HD version.  Now I can burninate in style.

Comment: I even added infomation to the origin of my name: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/what-is-the-origin-of-your-so-username/30933#30933