# Why isn't the advertising more relevant/targeted?

Tags: feature-request, tags, advertising

Trying to get [this ad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30974/looking-for-advertisement-for-switching-away-from-vss) shown to me, I though *hey, go to some VSS question and it will appear!*.

Much to my dismay, I've been reloading [VSS Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690766/vss-or-svn-for-a-net-project) for the last half an hour without that ad ever showing.

That got me thinking: Why aren't you looking at the context of a question (tags, keywords in the title/body) to provide an ad? Wouldn't that make the ads more successful by being more relevant? May be there is a flaw with my reasoning that I'm not seeing (I'm far from an ad guy).

Keep in mind that I'm not proposing deterministic ads, that being ads that are shown **only** when certain tags/keywords appear, but rather a random statistical model that weights ads and gives a weight boost to the relevant ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff bassically [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30981/question-relevant-advertising/30994#30994): we can target campaigns to a set of tags. Somtimes it makes sense to tag-target (both from a budgetary and effectiveness standpoint) and sometimes it doesn't. That's why we have a staff of people to help companies decide and measure this stuff. But to expand on this specific campaign...

Click-Thru-Rate (CTR) is measured in hundreths of a percent. A banner with a .20 CTR (which is actually pretty good) will require 500 impressions (times the ad is displayed) just to get one click. One click is pretty meaningless, so you need a *whole bunch* of impressions to get meaningful traffic.

So for the [VSS Is Dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30974/looking-for-advertisement-for-switching-away-from-vss) campaign, the [vss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vss) and [visual-sourcesafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-sourcesafe) tags have less than 300 questions. Add up the views on those questions over a month, and you are pretty far away from a *whole bunch*. We generally will not recommend or advise targeting tags with less than 1,000 questions.

Comment: Why not allow a tag focus with a general distribution ad?  The user gets ads spread across a site, but they also get a heavy concentration in a particular tag?

Comment: @C. Ross: we absolutely can do this (and have done it for a number of campaigns); it's really case-by-case thing.

Answer (score 1):

Alex can answer, but we already do this. Most of our advertising is tag-based.

There are some advertisers who want to do broad advertising as well as, or instead of, the tag-based stuff.

Comment: Oh, OK. So the relevance of a given advert depends on what the advertising party wanted then?

Comment: It depends on how much they are paying, lambdawaver.